# "no password supplied" in Rails 4 using establish_connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.2

I'm having to connect to a legacy database to import data to my new system, which is not something I've done before, so I'd appreciate someone helping me understand the setting I have wrong somewhere.

From the command line I can connect to the legacy database easily, with no password:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4
$ /usr/local/bin/psql -U adminuser -p 15432 legacydb
psql (9.2.4, server 8.4.5)
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 8.4.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

legacydb=# select count(*) from atable;
 count 
-------
  1005
(1 row)

legacydb=# \q
$
```

So in my Rails app, I defined app/models/atable.rb this way:

```
class Atable < ActiveRecord::Base

establish_connection(
  :adapter => "postgresql",
  :host => "localhost",
  :port => 15432,
  :username => "adminuser",
  :database => "legacydb"
)

end
```

But when I try to retrieve something I get the no password error:

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)

2.0.0-p247 :002 > t = Atable.first
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to figure out how to make Rails allow for a blank password, so I got the database administrator to add a new user/role with a password.  Substituting that information for :username => "foo" and :password => "bar" allowed Rails to talk to the database and me to retrieve records as one would normally expect.